# Content rendering after javascript - Zend

Tags: ajax, zend-framework, jquery, dojo

I can't  perform any js function fired by a dijit event unless setting the javascript file in the view itself.

I set various js files to use within my controller this way :

```
$layout = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance();
$view = $layout->getView();
$view->headScript()
            ->appendFile('/public/js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js', 'text/javascript')
            ->appendFile('/public/js/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js', 'text/javascript')
            ...
            ->appendFile('/public/js/functions.js', 'text/javascript');
```

which are echoed in the layout :

```
echo $this->headScript();
```

> note : all of them are loaded

But when my view is rendered The events bound to the dijits elements don't fire the functions in functions.js

For example I have this dijit element :

```
$business = new Zend_Dojo_Form_Element_FilteringSelect('business');
        $business ->setLabel("Etablissement :")
            -> setStoreId('businessStore')
            -> setStoreType('dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore')
            -> setStoreParams(array('url' => '/public/business/getbusinesses?all=true&'))
            -> setAttrib('searchAttr', 'nom')
            -> setAttrib('onchange',"cB()")
            -> setRequired(true)
            -> setValue('business');
```

and the js function :

```
function cB() {
    alert("changed");
}
```

But even if I wrap cB() like this it doesn't work :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function cB() {
        alert("changed");
    }
});
```

Do somone has an idea ? I'm stuck with this javascript issue all over my Zend application =(

thanks !

Comment: You likely don't need to have '/public/' as part of the url for the javascript includes. Can you confirm that you can pull up the javascript files directly in the browser?

Comment: Yes each of them are correctly loaded

Comment: To confirm, the directory structure where these files are is (assuming Zend Framework standard directories) PROJECT_ROOT/public/public/js/... ? And the vhost is pointing to PROJECT_ROOT/public?

Comment: I just found the answer even if I don't really understand it, I removed every form decorator and the javascript functions work now. Sorry for the inconvenience